# Why isn't AutocompleteFragment responding after the first search?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-places-autocomplete

I'm using an autocomplete_fragment to allow my users to search for places. After clicking the fragment it opens up the search menu, and you can type and the suggestions will appear. However, after clicking on any place the "onPlaceSelected" method won't run. After that clicking on the fragment won't make it respond either.

This fragment is in an activity with a map. I tried using the same fragment (same code and same layout) on another activity which only had text and it worked as expected. What could be happening in this activity that is making this behavior occur?

Here's the code showing the onCreate method, which calls some other methods which I wouldn't expect to be the source of the problem.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Initialize Places.
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "myapikey");
        // Create a new Places client instance.
        PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

        // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
        autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

// Specify the types of place data to return.
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

// Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i("CHECK4", "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i("CHECK4", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });


        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapView = mapFragment.getView();
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        anchorView = findViewById(R.id.anchorView);
        buttonRoutes = findViewById(R.id.buttonRoutes);
        buttonMenu = findViewById(R.id.buttonMenu);

        buttonRoutes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent routesIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, RoutesActivity.class);
                startActivity(routesIntent);
            }
        });
        buttonMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent routesIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(routesIntent);
            }
        });

        routeIds = getIdsList();
        routeTitles = getTitlesList();
        routeCamera = getCameraList();
        routeZoom = getZoomList();

        initializeAllRoutes();
        initializeAllStops();


        RRdistance = new HashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Double>();
        initializeRRdistance();

        geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

        checkFirstTime();
    }
```

For some reason, something in this particular activity is breaking the autocompletefragment. No errors are shown, just nothing happens.

Edit: I tried removing different parts of my activity until the autocomplete fragment worked, and I managed to find what was going on that way. The OnActivityResult method for some reason is the cause of the problem. Deleting the method made the autocomplete fragment work.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Can you try isolating Autocomplete to rule out issues in your other code that could be conflicting with it?

Comment: Also can you try posting your full code so that we can reproduce this from our side?

Comment: @evan I edited the post to add the solution I found.

Comment: Thanks for your update, glad to hear your issue is now fixed. You may want to post your solution and accept your own answer for the community's sake. :)

Answer (score 0):

The OnActivityResult method for some reason is the cause of the problem. Deleting the method made the autocomplete fragment work. I was using this method before migrating to the new places API.